# What is the easiest way to create a webapp from an interactive Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook that plots some data and lets the user interact with it via a slider.

What would be the easiest way to make a web app with a similar functionality? (reusing as much of the code...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is to use [voilà](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html).

After installing you just have to run:

```
voila <path-to-notebook> <options>
```

And you will have a server running your notebook as a web app, with all the input code omitted.

Answer (score 4):

[AppMode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) is "A Jupyter extension that turns notebooks into web applications".

From the README:

> Appmode consist of a server-side and a notebook extension for Jupyter.
>   Together these two extensions provide the following features:
>
> - One can view any notebook in appmode by clicking on the Appmode button in the toolbar. Alternatively one can change the url from
>     baseurl/notebooks/foo.ipynb to baseurl/apps/foo.ipynb. This also
>     allows for direct links into appmode.
> - When a notebook is opened in appmode, all code cells are automatically executed. In order to present a clean UI, all code cells
>     are hidden and the markdown cells are read-only.
> - A notebook can be opened multiple times in appmode without interference. This is achieved by creating temporary copies of the
>     notebook for each active appmode view. Each appmode view has its
>     dedicated ipython kernel. When an appmode page is closed the kernel is
>     shutdown and the temporary copy gets removed.
> - To allow for passing information between notebooks via url parameters, the current url is injected into the variable
>     jupyter_notebook_url.

Answer (score 4):

To be complete - there exists also https://www.streamlit.io/ .

I still dont understand the exact difference between  `voila` and `streamlit`.
 At the moment I just struggle with the possibility to re-run everything with new parameters... I have bad luck with `voila` still.

Edit: I see that `streamlit` requires a raw python, not .ipynb, this fact would mean that this answer is completely wrong, I will search a bit more on `streamlit` before further action/comment.

Edit2: `Voila` looks great. However, I found few things that uncover the underlying complexity and thus a troubles that may arise.

- *callbacks*. Widgets work great in jupyter, but since it is not possible to re-run one cell, sometimes the logic must be modified to work in `Voila`.
- *interactive java* objects need a special treatment, e.g. `matplotlib` has a cheap solution, but there was nothing for e.g. jsroot
- *links*. It is easy to create (a file and) a download link in jupyter, Voila can also serve a file, but it needs another extra treatment.

After all, I pose myself a question - *is it better to learn many tricks and modifications to jupyter or to use some other system?* I am going to see if `streamlit` can give em some answer.

Comment: There is some related discussions [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/thoughts-and-experiences-from-using-jupyter-in-enterprise/2572/6?u=fomightez) and just above that [also](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/thoughts-and-experiences-from-using-jupyter-in-enterprise/2572/7?u=fomightez) on the Jupyter Discourse Forum for those considering options.

Comment: Actually coming back to this discussion after sometime and am I glad to see streamline being mentioned here. This was non-existent approx a year ago. Thats how this whole ML/DataSci eco-system moves. At Warp speed. I have a need for a MVP for a ML app and I will be considering Streamlit for that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) framework. You can reuse all your code. To convert the notebook to web app you will need to add the YAML header in the first cell of the notebook (very similar to R Markdown). The widgets are generated based on YAML. The end-user can tweak widgets values and click the `Run` button to execute the notebook from the top to the bottom. You can easily hide the notebook's code (if you want) by setting the `show-code: False` in the YAML. The example notebook and corresponding web app are below.

#### Example of the notebook with YAML header

[image]

#### Example web app generated from notebook with Mercury

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Jupyter Dashboards Bundlers](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards_bundlers/) extension from the Jupyter Incubator is one way to do it while retaining interactivity.

EDIT: While `pip` installing this package will also install the `cms` package dependency, like `dashboard_bundlers`, `cms` needs to be explicitly enabled/quick-setup as a notebook extension for the dashboard tools to work.

Comment: This project has been retired.  (Though it may still work).

Answer (score 1):

@raphaelts has the right idea and should be the accepted answer. As of Dec 2019, Voila is the most appropriate method to deploy Jupyter notebooks to production as a stand alone webapp. Think internal datascience teams sharing their analytics workload with internal C-Suite teams using SPA stlye Notebooks with all the code hidden and custom GUI/interactions thrown in. Recently discussed on HN
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20160634 and the official announcement from the Jupyter maintainer https://blog.jupyter.org/and-voil%C3%A0-f6a2c08a4a93[enter link description here](https://blog.jupyter.org/and-voil%C3%A0-f6a2c08a4a93)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, [voilà](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html) is a very powerful tool which hides the input cells from your notebooks and therefore provides a clean interface. In order to deploy your notebook with voilà you need to follow the specific steps of your organization. But if you want to quickly run it on your machine, simply install it with `pip install voila`. Then you can enter start from the command-line: `voila my_notebook.ipynb` or use the "Voila" button which should have appeared in your Jupyter notebook.

Note, however, that using voilà is only one part of the story. You also need to build the required interactivity, ie. to set up how to respond to input changes. There are quite a few frameworks for this.

- The simplest one is to use the `interact` function or the `observe` method from the Ipywidgets library. This is very direct, but things can easily get out of control as you start having more and more widgets and complexity.
- There are complete frameworks, some of them mentioned above.  E.g. streamlit, dash and holoviz. These are very powerful and suited for larger projects.
- But if you want to keep it simple, I also recommend to check out [autocalc](https://pypi.org/project/autocalc/). It is a very easy-to-use library, which lets you define the dependencies between your widgets/variables and let all the recalculation be triggered automatically. A tutorial can be found [here](https://medium.com/@andras.gefferth/create-a-simple-app-quickly-using-jupyter-notebook-312bdbb9d224?source=friends_link&sk=2e220a15767fc4de8145c625e1918842).

Disclaimer: I am the author of the autocalc package.

Answer (score 0):

There is web-based IDE that allows conversion of Jupiler playbook into python web app, called [anvil.works](https://anwil.works)

Follow this how-to article for more details https://anvil.works/learn/tutorials/jupyter-notebook-to-web-app

Hope this helps.