# How to serve an interactive jupyter notebook cell via desktop or web app?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm aware of similar previous questions such as:

[What is the easiest way to create a webapp from an interactive Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867031/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-webapp-from-an-interactive-jupyter-notebook)

[Exporting Interactive Jupyter Notebook to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151181/exporting-interactive-jupyter-notebook-to-html)

However they are old and outdated (for example dashboards_bundlers is no longer supported...)

Is there any recent progress allowing to turn an interactive notebook into a web/desktop app easily?

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) that allows to easily convert the notebook to web application. You need to add the YAML header as RAW cell to your notebook.

The example notebook:

```
---
title: My app
description: My first notebook shared on Mercury
params:
    greetings:
        input: select
        label: Select greetings
        value: Cześć
        choices: [Cześć, Hello, Hi, Salut, Ciao]
    year:
        input: slider
        label: Select year
        value: 2022
        min: 2021
        max: 2030
---
```

```py
greetings = "Cześć"
year = 2022
```

```py
print(f"{greetings} {year}")
```

The above notebook will generate a web app like in the screenshot below:
[image: Mercury example app]

There is an option to hide the code and only show the output to non-programming users.

The Mercury is built on top of Django, can be easily deployed to any server/cloud.