# Is there a way to make a web app from a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, web-applications, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook that accepts user-input via the input() python function. It then takes the input and uses it to a run a model and then outputs/plots the result. Is there a way to create a web-app that does this? Of course, the web-app must also accept user-input and have access to my model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to create a webapp from an interactive Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867031/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-webapp-from-an-interactive-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already made a plugin for that. Try `appmode` for Jupyter Notebook. [Here's the repository.](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) Hope that works out!

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework called [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) that can convert Jupyter Notebook into web app by adding YAML header. Please add **Raw** cell at the the beginning of the notebook:

```yaml
title: My app title
description: What is your app doing?
params:
    my_variable:
        input: text
        label: Please provide input
```

In the next cell please add variable with some default value

```py
my_variable = "some text"
```

Then you can have your Notebook code. The Mercury framework will convert Notebook into web app.

If you would like to hide the code. Just add `show-code: False` after `description` in the YAML header and your users will only see outputs.

The Notebook can be easily deployed to the cloud.

Comment: Mr. Plonski is actually the main developer of Mercury. People usually mention this on SO when they recommend their work for solving a given problem.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work like that. If you want to make a web app, you'll make GUI with html/css for taking input and displaying output. Your python code will work as the `backend` of the application. You can use a python framework like `flask` to make things easier.